# AlertDialog Custom layout views not accessible android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have a method responsible for showing `AlertDialog` and it has a custom layout which includes a `EditText`, and OnPositive button click I am trying to get the value of edit text but the `EditText.getText()` always return empty.

**Code:**

```
private void showForgetPassDialog() {

        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_forgot_pass, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.forgot_password));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.reset_pass));
        final EditText emailTxt  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email_field);
        emailReset = emailTxt.getText().toString();
        String positiveText = getString(R.string.submit);
        builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "test :"+emailReset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(!emailReset.equals("") && isValidEmail(emailReset)){
                            resetPassword(emailReset);
                        }else{
                            emailTxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_email));
                        }

                    }
                });

        String negativeText = getString(R.string.cancel);
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(LoginActivity.this,R.color.colorAccentDark));
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(LoginActivity.this,R.color.PrimaryBlue));

            }
        });
        dialog.setView(view);
        // display dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

> XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    >
    <EditText
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:id="@+id/email_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/email_label"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#484848" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/login_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_field"
        android:background="#e1e1e1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move

```
emailReset = emailTxt.getText().toString();
```

to inside of onClick listener.

```
builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Here!!!!!!!!!
                    emailReset = emailTxt.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "test :"+emailReset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(!emailReset.equals("") && isValidEmail(emailReset)){
                        resetPassword(emailReset);
                    }else{
                        emailTxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_email));
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: but i am unable to set the editText error message as when it enters into else statement alert dialog closes up without setting error message to edittext

Comment: @MehvishFaisal once you click on the button, the Alert Dialog will dismiss itself along with a callback to onClick listener